# Angular ng-tag- input max-tag not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I want to restrict some fixed tags then after it not able to add new tags

```
<tags-input ng-model="searchTerm"
            display-property="Name" 
            add-from-autocomplete-only="true"
            replace-spaces-with-dashes='false'
           max-tags='4'
        placeholder="Search option"
          >
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length='3'></auto-complete>
```

i have added ng-tag-input js and also do all needful changes what is the problem for max tag?

Comment: default behavior of `max-tags` is to change ng-model into `invalid` state and add `ng-invalid` class to input, if you want to restrict the user from entering new tag create `custom directive` for that, because this feature is not yet in production https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/210

Answer (score 0):

use a custom directive

```
app.directive('enforceMaxTags', function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                var maxTags = attrs.maxTags ? parseInt(attrs.maxTags, '10') : null;

                ngModelCtrl.$validators.checkLength = function(value) {

                    if (value && maxTags && value.length > maxTags) {
                        value.splice(value.length - 1, 1);
                    }
                    return value ? value : [];
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

solution from https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/210